# jQuery target $(window) on a specific webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just wondering if there is any easy way i can target $(window) to only work on localhost/website/hello and not localhost/website/bye

I've made a easy test script,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        alert('Hello World');
    }
});
```

The problem is that this snippet will work on all pages where the script is loaded...

Comment: have you tried RegEx to test the url match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the page path name first and then apply a condition

```
var url = location.pathname;



if ("url:contains('localhost/website/hello')") {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        alert('Hello World');
    }

  }


  else ("url:contains('localhost/website/bye')") {
    //do something else
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `location.href` value to check what page your are loading.

```
if (location.href == "your_page") {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            alert('Hello World');
        }
    });
}
```

To match a set of different pages use Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/T6hf2/2/)**

```
var currentPage = window.location.href.match(/website\/(.*)/)[1];

if(currentPage === 'hello/'){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            alert('Hello World');
        }
    });
}
```

so basically anything after `website/` will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( window.location.hostname.indexOf("localhost") != -1 ) {
  alert('on localhost'); 
}
if( window.location.pathname.indexOf("hello") != -1 ) {
 alert('path contains "hello"');  
}
```

you can use the [window.location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952653.aspx) object to parse the url and check against specific parts.